# With NuGet Pack, is it possible to keep spaces in the target filename?

Tags: nuget

I am using the command:

```
nuget pack "myNuspec.nuspec" -OutputDirectory "SomeDirectory"
```

and in the nuspec file I have the line

```
<file src="SomeFolder\File With Spaces.xlsx" target="TargetFolder" />
```

However once the packaging is completed, in the resulting `nupkg` file, I see the file `File%20With%20Spaces.xlsx`, which has been encoded with `%20`. I wondered, is there a way to pack this file, which keeps the space in the resulting filename?

Comment: Same issue...apparently this is not a new issue

Comment: I crated a ticket: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5726

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this was a bug at one point but has since been fixed: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2389

No idea what version it was fixed in though...

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this with the wildcard file copy.

```
<file src="SomeFolder\*.xlsx" target="TargetFolder" />
```